# I am calculating the time of a numpy array and normal list by appending items in list and array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

While appending items in an numpy array,it is throwing the following error
TypeError: Required argument 'object' (pos 1) not found

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import time

list = []
start = time.time()
def normalsqrt(a):

    for b in range(a):
        list.append(b**(1/2))
normalsqrt(1000)
print((time.time() - start) * 1000)


a = np.array()
start = time.time()

def numpy_sqrt(size):
    for b in range(size):
        np.concatenate((a, np.array([a[b]])))

numpy_sqrt(1000)
print((time.time() - start) * 1000)
```

Comment: This is not a good way to test times, use `timeit` but you also don't seem to have asked a question. If you're going to try and time things properly, they shouldn't be being looked up in the global scope. You also shouldn't be using `list` as a variable name because that's a builtin.

Comment: It's `np.array([])` for initializing empty array.

Comment: i have used np.array([]) and still its giving the error..np.append(a, [a[b]])
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Comment: @percusse ......

Comment: So you're trying to index an empty array?

Comment: i am adding items in an numpy array which is initialized empty

Comment: But you're not, because you're using the syntax to index the `a` array.

Comment: i have used this np.append(a, [a[b]]) but still it gives the same error

Comment: And what do you expect `[a[b]]` to mean when you start this loop and `a` is an empty array?

Comment: while adding and using  append function and using [a[b]] in a second parameter i'm expecting the array to add values in it..The second parameter in append is for adding values in an array

Comment: You should **never use numpy this way**.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how can i fix it?

Comment: Don't concatenate/append items to numpy arrays in a loop, that is quadratic time. It is slow and inefficient. If your algorithm *must* work this way, use a list then convert to an array at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make your list function self contained:

```
def normalsqrt(a):
    alist=[]
    for b in range(a):
        alist.append(b**(1/2))
    return alist

In [225]: normalsqrt(3)
Out[225]: [0.0, 1.0, 1.4142135623730951]
```

In `ipython`, running `timeit` is trivial:

```
In [226]: %timeit normalsqrt(1000)
288 µs ± 278 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

Now for the concatenate approach.

First your array initialization is wrong:

```
In [228]: np.array()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-228-e4f3b47dc252> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array()

TypeError: Required argument 'object' (pos 1) not found
```

You should have discovered this right away when testing this code in an interactive session.  I never write Python code without such a session at hand to test code pieces.

Repeated concatenation is tricky.  First it is slow, as the time tests will show.  Second, it is hard to create a proper start array.  You really need to understand `concatenate` and array creating well to do it correctly.

Even Ihad to try a couple of things before I got this function right:

```
def numpy_sqrt(size):
    arr = np.zeros((0,), dtype=int)
    for b in range(size):
        value = np.array([b**(1/2)])
        arr = np.concatenate((arr, value), axis=0)
    return arr
```

Both `arr` and `value` have to be 1d arrays.  And `concatenate` returns a new array; it does not operate in place.

```
In [233]: numpy_sqrt(3)
Out[233]: array([0.        , 1.        , 1.41421356])
```

And the times - 26 times slower than the list version:

```
In [235]: %timeit numpy_sqrt(1000)
7.92 ms ± 304 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

But another, simpler way of getting the same array:

```
In [237]: np.arange(3)**(1/2)
Out[237]: array([0.        , 1.        , 1.41421356])
In [238]: timeit np.arange(1000)**(1/2)
103 µs ± 22.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: The error occurs before that function, in the `a = np.array()` line.

Comment: how it can be fixed? i am not getting it

Comment: Have you looked at the `np.array` docs?  `np.array([1, 2, 3])` is the normal way of creating an array. It looks like you have just substituted `array` for `list`, without trying to learn the basics and understanding how they are different.